# Exporting a class which uses managed handles?

Tags: c++-cli

I'm trying to create a native wrapper around a .Net library in C++/CLI, so that regular C++ code can consume it.  For this example, let's say this is the C# code I'm trying to wrap:

```
class Foo
{
    public Bar GetBar() {...}
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
    public void Baz() {...}
}
```

I'm basically trying to do roughly this in C++/CLI (dll project):

```
class __declspec(dllexport) NativeFoo
{
public:
    NativeBar GetBar();
    std::string GetName();
    void SetName(const std::string &value);

private:
    Foo ^m_foo;
};

class __declspec(dllexport) NativeBar
{
    friend class NativeFoo;
public:
    void Baz();

private:
    Bar(Bar ^bar);

    Bar ^m_bar;
};
```

That way, a C++ library could link to this, use NativeFoo as if it's a regular C++ class.  Internally, NativeFoo would convert parameters to pass the implementation over to m_foo, marshal anything managed back into a native representation and return that to its caller...

However, the problem I'm running into is I can't have managed members of an unmanaged class:

```
error C3265: cannot declare a managed 'm_bar' in an unmanaged 'NativeFoo'
```

Similarly I can't mark NativeFoo as "ref" (being a managed class itself) because then I can't export it:

```
C3386: 'NativeFoo' : __declspec(dllexport)/__declspec(dllimport) cannot be applied to a managed type
```

What's the right way to use managed pointers in my C++ objects?

Comment: You can export managed functions with __declspec(dllexport), not classes.  In general, you are overlooking a chicken and egg problem.  Somebody is going to have to load the CLR so that the managed code can execute.  The dllexport directive creates a stub that takes care of that.  But that's not ideal.  You first need to decide if you create a managed program that calls native code (easy) or a native program that executes managed code (hard).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `gcroot` to declare a managed handle on an unmanaged type. You need this for any unmanaged type, whether it's being dllexported or not.

There's a [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/481fa11f.aspx) on it with some good information & some samples.

I believe you'll end up with something like this:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) NativeFoo
{
public:
    NativeBar GetBar();
    std::string GetName();
    void SetName(const std::string &value);

private:
    gcroot<Foo^> m_foo;
};
```

Comment: Good answer.  I started with gcroot and later discovered auto_gcroot.  i.e. `msclr::auto_gcroot<Foo^> m_foo;`  Remember use this with `#include <msclr/auto_gcroot.h>`.

Comment: The shortcoming of this answer is Foo must be declared "ref class", and a native C++ header cannot have that declaration.